# Determining if root logger is set to DEBUG level in Python?

Tags: python, logging, decorator, python-logging

If I set the logging module to DEBUG with a command line parameter like this:

```
if (opt["log"] == "debug"):
  logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

How can I later tell if the logger was set to DEBUG?  I'm writing a decorator that
will time a function if True flag is passed to it, and if no flag is given, it defaults
to printing timing information when the root logger is set to DEBUG.

Comment: You will eventually want to use something specific instead of coupling this to the logger, such as opt["time_functions"] (which you might default to True/False based on some other option).

Answer (score 129, accepted):

```
logging.getLogger().getEffectiveLevel()
```

`logging.getLogger()` without arguments gets the root level logger.

http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.getEffectiveLevel

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  I was doing something like that (except passing explicit "root" to getLogger), but I was doing it in the __init__ function of my decorator, before the logger was set to debug :\

Comment: If you want the name of level, not the number, you can use this to convert the number to a string (like 'INFO'): logging.getLevelName()

Comment: @guettli, getLevelName() requires one argument containing the level whose  textual representation you want to get. So the call is actually this beast: `logging.getLevelName(logging.getLogger().getEffectiveLevel())`. It would be nice to have a simpler syntax when all you want is the string for the current level.

Comment: To convert the level integer to the name: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#levels

Answer (score 134):

Actually, there's one better: **use the code `logging.getLogger().isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG)`**. I found it while trying to understand what to do with the result of `getEffectiveLevel()`.

Below is the code that the logging module itself uses.

```
def getEffectiveLevel(self):
    """
    Get the effective level for this logger.

    Loop through this logger and its parents in the blogger hierarchy,
    looking for a non-zero logging level. Return the first one found. 
    """
    logger = self
    while logger:
        if logger.level:
            return logger.level
        logger = logger.parent
    return NOTSET

def isEnabledFor(self, level):
    """
    Is this logger enabled for level ‘level’?
    """
    if self.manager.disable >= level:
        return 0
    return level >= self.getEffectiveLevel()
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it does the same thing with lower runtime complexity.

Answer (score 3):

Just

```
logging.getLogger().level == logging.DEBUG
```

Comment: This is a bad answer; it only works to check an _exact_ level not _effective_ like a comment elsewhere. `isEnabledFor()` exists for this reason!