# python script with debug level

Tags: python, debugging

I'm a newbie. I'm trying a script a 'snmpwalk' in PYTHON which returns list of OID from the starting ID mentioned.

I see Python has various options over shell scripts, so I choose this.

I need few ideas on how to do and process it.

If I execute the script with *--debug* option it should list all the OIDs in the stdout (I meant the executing screen) &
Always it should log the output of the bash commands to a log file.

Then I will check for any anomalies.

Please someone give me the kickstart on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has some great standard libraries that will help you massively with this. For logging, use the aptly-named [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) library. Combine that with [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to detect the debug flag and you got yourself a shell script with customisable log levels.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. But I see that logging is very helpful to give some system messages when there is a bug in script.

What I feel is to display the output of an execution when an option is enabled.

Can u share some scripts which you think apt? I tried a to dig on logging but couldn't make it clear!

Comment: @hashjagz if you feel like I answered your question, would you be so kind to mark it as the answer? Thanks!

Comment: I'm a newbie. it requires few reputations to cast my vote.

Btw, can u please respond for above?

Comment: @hashjagz also see this answer about getting the logger level: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1987484/238310 which you can then use in a simple `if` statement. Or you can set a simple `DEBUG = False` at the top of your code and then edit it later... or maybe pass a `debug` argument to your functions?

Comment: thanks I upvoted, but my reputation needs to be increased. But I did liked it :) Thanks.