# Python: Perform operation dependent on logging level

Tags: python, logging

One of my `logger.debug()` statements takes input that's fairly labour-intensive.

I know that I should do `logger.debug("The spam is %s", spam_temperature)` rather than `logger.debug("The spam is {}".format(spam_temperature))`.  The problem is that the operations I need to perform to actually find out the `spam_temperature` are quite CPU-intensive, and I have no use for them if the logging level is, say, `INFO`.

What is the best practice in a case like this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself - I added 
`python
if not logging.getLogger().isEnabledFor(logging.DEBUG):
    return`

before the section I wanted to avoid.

(I got the inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/a/27849836/3061818)